# howto get the destination address of accepted sockets?

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I know you can get the destination address for messages coming into a SOCK_DGRAM socket by using recvmsg. I would like to know how to get the destination address (from peer perspective) for a socket created by calling the accept function on a socket of type SOCK_STREAM. In other words, how can I get the destination address of the SYN packet that caused accept to return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps with [getpeername](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xns/getpeername.html) system call?

Comment: Actually I was looking for getsockname but thanks because reading up on getpeername led me to it.

Answer (score 1):

The function you look for is `getpeername`.